# node --enable-source-maps not outputting function names

Tags: node.js, source-maps

I am trying the new experimental node flag `--enable-source-maps` from the article [Source maps in Node.js](https://medium.com/@nodejs/source-maps-in-node-js-482872b56116) and while it outputs the correct line numbers, it doesn't appear to be outputting function names.

Given the following:

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "node-sourcemaps",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

`index.js`

```js
const functionA = () => {
  functionB()
}

const functionB = () => {
  functionC()
}

const functionC = () => {
  functionD()
}

const functionD = () => {
  throw new Error('Roh Ruh')
}

functionA()
```

Generating the transpiled output and source map:

```
> npx webpack ./index.js --devtool source-map --target node --mode production
```

And then executing it using node and the flag:

```
❯ node --enable-source-maps .\dist\main.js
Error: Roh Ruh
    at o (D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\main.js:1:970)
        -> D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\index.js:14:9
    at n (D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\main.js:1:952)
        -> D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\index.js:10:3
    at r (D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\main.js:1:940)
        -> D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\index.js:6:3
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\main.js:1:992)   
        -> D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\index.js:2:3
    at r (D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\main.js:1:110)
        -> D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:22 
    at D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\main.js:1:902
        -> D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:83:10 
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\main.js:1:911)   
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)

    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
```

You can see that the line numbers are correct, however the function names are obscured.

If I repeat the same but using the `source-map-support` package

```js
require('source-map-support').install()

const functionA = () => {
  functionB()
}

const functionB = () => {
  functionC()
}

const functionC = () => {
  functionD()
}

const functionD = () => {
  throw new Error('Roh Ruh')
}

functionA()
```

Executing it using node but without the flag:

```
❯ node .\dist\main.js

D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\index.js:16
  throw new Error('Roh Ruh')
        ^
Error: Roh Ruh
    at functionD (D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\index.js:16:9)   
    at functionC (D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\index.js:12:3)   
    at functionB (D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\index.js:8:3)    
    at Object.call (D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\index.js:4:3)  
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:19:22)
    at D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap:83:10     
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\spikes\node-sourcemaps-spike\dist\main.js:1:911)   
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)     
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
```

You can see the correct line numbers and function names.

Is this a limitation of node sourcemap support or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: what version is your node? it looks like support for the `--enable-source-maps` flag was added in v12.12.0

Comment: I using node v12.13.0

Answer (score -2):

It looks like in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support#cli-usage) for source-map-support, you have 2 options:

**CLI Usage**

```
// edited to match your example
node -r source-map-support/register dist/main.js
```

**Programmatic Usage**

To use this way, you simply put this line at the top of your file

```js
require('source-map-support').install();
```

Either one of these will work. I believe this package is more of an alternative to the `--enable-source-maps` flag and you don't need to use them together

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If I use the `source-map-support` package I get the results I'm after. I'm trying to reproduce the same results without using the  `source-map-support` by using nodes built in `--enable-source-maps` flag, however in this case I get the line numbers but not the function names

Comment: sorry, it seems i misunderstood the question. it seems like the `--enable-source-maps` flag is working as intended, i don't think it is intended to display the function names, just to point to the original file. it seems like adding the function line and names is a feature of the `source-map-support` package @kimsagro